# Radon-Nikodym derivatives with parameters?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose that $(A,\Sigma_A)$ and $(X,\Sigma_X)$ are measurable spaces, and that
$$
 \mu,\nu \: : \: A \times \Sigma_X \rightarrow [0,1]
$$
are [Markov kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel#Formal_definition), i.e. probability measures on $X$ parametrized measurably by $A$. Suppose that $\nu(a) \ll \mu(a)$ for every $a \in A$. Then is it possible to find **jointly measurable** $f : A \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that every $f(a,-) : X \to \mathbb{R}$ for $a \in A$ is a version of the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\nu(a)}{d\mu(a)}$?

This is trivially true if $A$ is discrete, since then one can choose an arbitrary version of $\frac{d\nu(a)}{d\mu(a)}$ for every $a$. But in general, the problem is to guarantee the joint measurability of $f$.

As far as it matters, I'm primarily interested in the case where $(A,\Sigma_A)$ is standard Borel.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes, and this is covered in Dan Rudolph’s book, the Fundamentals of Measurable Dynamics.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: thank you! The standard Radon-Nikodym theorem appears in that book as Exercise 2.15, but I don't see any other version of it anywhere. Do you have a more precise pointer?

Comment: If $(X, \Sigma_X)$ is a separable measurable space, this seems to be precisely Theorem 58 (page 52 in my version) in Dellacherie & Meyer "Probability and Potential B: Theory of Martingales". A footnote also claims the separability assumption is indespensible, citing "Seminaire de Probabilites X, Springer-Verlag, Lecture Notes in M. 511, pp.115-116".

Comment: @Steve: that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: To complete the list of references here, many joint measurability results for versions of the Radon-Nikodym derivative can be found in [Cutler, "Some Measure Theoretic and Topological Results for Measure Valued and Set Valued Stochastic Processes" (PhD), 1984].